# Textbox automatically return value

Tags: c#, textbox

I am planning to create a .aspx and .cs file. All I have is basically 2 textbox.

[image: textbox]

(Please disregards the button in the middle.)

the first textbox is to input the sentence, and I want the other textbox automatically following what I type in the first box. So basically its similar like google translate, but it's not translating the text. Just simply following the text I input in the first textbox.

Any Idea how to do it?

Comment: Use textchange event of textbox1. And in textchange function set textbox2.text.....and before setting text of textbox2 execute steps of converting the text

Comment: can you show me some example?

Comment: Share ur code...what u have done

Answer (score 0):

You can **also** achieve this using `JavaScript`, see attached code sample.

It uses `onKeyUp` event for `html inputs`' , in your code replace input control ids with clientid snippets as indicated in comments.

Also see this - [how to add onKeyUp to asp.net textbox](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/add-onkeyup-to-aspnet-textbox.html) to make this happen in your code.

```js
function copyText()
{
  //var textBoxFirstClientID = '<%= textBox1.ClientID %>';
  //var textBoxSecondClientID = '<%= textBox2.ClientID %>';
  var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1');// use textBoxFirstClientID
  var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2');//use textBoxSecondClientID
  txt2.value = txt1.value;
}
```

```html
<asp:textbox id="textBox1">your asp.net textbox 1</asp:button>
<input type="text"  id="txt1" onkeyup="copyText()">
<br>
<br>
<asp:textbox id="textBox2">your asp.net textbox 2</asp:textbox>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```